# mPDF rotates some images

Tags: image, rotation, mpdf

Some jpegs that are correctly displayed in HTML or using a photo editor are rotated counter-clockwise in the PDF generated by mPDF. Is there jpeg metadata that causes this to occur?

Answer (score 0):

The value for IDF0.Orientation results in mPDF rotating JPEGs for values 3, 6 and 8. The PHP imagerotate function can be used to rotate these so they appear correctly in the PDF.